# Trello: run a sed-like script when creating a card with email-to-board

Tags: automation, trello

[Trello](https://trello.com) has an awesome feature of [creating cards](https://support.atlassian.com/trello/docs/creating-cards-by-email/) or adding comment to a card from an email.

Sadly, emails come with a lot of crap (corporate signatures, disclaimers, attached logos...) that create clutter in trello boards.

So I would like to have Trello run a script when receiving those emails to

- strip some regex away (or any kind of text processing)
- remove attachments, based on file type, size, name...

Trello Butler (the 'automation' button) could use triggers like 'when card content changes', but there is no obvious action that would filter the content.

*The question is:* how can I configure Trello/Butler to pass the received text to some text processor (like sed for instance) to "sanitize" its inputs?

Note: Maybe there's a way using [the send HTTP request action](https://support.atlassian.com/trello/docs/issuing-http-requests/), but I don't know much of that part, and it doesn't look like it can deal with attachments

Comment: While there is very little documentation regarding Trello Butler's triggers, a [blog post](https://blog.trello.com/butler-power-up-trello-automation) regarding Butler mentions that it supports 'When card is added' as a trigger which should cover your use case. I don't have Trello handy to go any further.

Comment: @plunker : thanks! I'm still concerned about the action (run sed) than the trigger (when card changes) though

Comment: You might need to specify more information about what you need to strip out (or probably what information you want to keep). Can't really help you determine sed arguments without more context.

Comment: @plunker: it's not about what sed expression to use, it's about how to call sed (or whatever it is possible to call that would do a similar job). Rephrasing the OP